# Separating unrelated data to be mapped back for later use

Tags: design

I'm having a use case of a node editor, my node editor has "Sockets", dots highlighted here
[image]

Sockets are distinguished by "EntryType" class, which is a "blueprint" definition for Entry, in this case type name is "Number", sockets have to access color information according to EntryType.

Here's an Entry highlighted

[image]

EntryType has to store it's shape (You can see the green socket has squarish shape, while other rhombus) and color.

The problem is that it makes no sense for EntryType to store color and shape information, because EntryType should just indicate a blueprint for entries, and we are mixing completely unrelated data.

So is there a way to separate unrelated data, so we can map it (Visual information) back. Or is that just a made-up problem, that will not affect myself and my development speed?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Why is `EntryType` storing anything at all? `Entry` should have a type, a color, a shape, a smell and whatever else it needs.

Comment: @Mat EntryType is storing type for an entry, if you see that last image attached, there's instance of those for each field. EntryType describes which types are compatible (e.g. List isn't compatible with Number, e.t.c

Comment: If I understood you well, you're asking how to separate the internal definition of inputs and outputs for a node (what type the inputs and outputs are) from the *visual presentation* of a particular input (the connector socket - e.g. the blue rhombus represents a scalar value, in this case a number, while the green square represents a list, I suppose)?

Comment: One thing you could do is have your nodes store descriptions of inputs and outputs (e.g. something like `{ inputs: [number, number], output: [number] }`, and then when rendering, use that data to construct the sockets (say, via a factory function) as thin views (thin in the sense that they have almost no behavior, and no knowledge of what they represent). Basically map the type to the presentation. The sockets need a ref to the type description (could just be an index), and they also need to be able to detect a drag & drop operation, that you can handle in some other place.

Comment: not really inputs and outputs, those sockets just have the EntryType attached, and the actual EntryType has the color information, yes indeed shapes and colors to differentiate between scalars and other values

Comment: `Map<EntryType, EntryVisualInfo>`?

Comment: @user253751 i thought about this too but then I have to make a global variable for that "mapping" or pass it through parameters (waste of time) I think I'll just make an interface for VisualInfo, hopefully it won't bring any problems

Comment: @ishidex2 the mapping doesn't change, right? it's okay for constants to be global.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about displaying encapsulated information without hard-coding visual properties in multiple places, you might be able to to use a visitor.

`EntryType` would have an abstract `display` method that takes an argument such as `DisplayBuilder`, which would have various methods to construct a visual representation based on *semantics* rather than *formatting*.

If `EntryTypeFoo` previously needed hard-coding of "green square", `EntryTypeFoo.display` would instead call a method in `DisplayBuilder` that corresponds to whatever semantics led to the "green square" representation in the first place.

For example, if "green square" means "editable":

```
void display(DisplayBuilder builder) {
  builder.addEditableNumber(88);
}
```

This way, `EntryTypeFoo` is just telling some opaque object (`DisplayBuilder`) what its own semantics are, without needing to know how that information is going to be used.

Whatever logic is responsible for rendering a particular `EntryType` would then call `display` with a `DisplayBuilder` to extract a visual representation, which it can then insert in the appropriate place in the UI. This also allows `EntryType` to be independent of the UI framework.